# getting substrings in each array index using a delimeter

Tags: java, arrays

given an array

```
String original[]={"string0,10","string1,45","string2,3", "string3,67"};
```

how would I use the comma as a delimeter to create another array with only the names?

I need an array that looks something like this:

```
String result[]={"string0","string1","string2", "string3"};
```

Comment: so the second line is your desired output? Have you tried this ?

Comment: Will the name be always the first part of each item?

Comment: @Jibran yes but the name can also have numbers and special characters. I just need to figure out how to get the substring up until the comma at each index of the original array.

Comment: You can try java 8 solution given below by @schidu. It is elegant and will do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String original[]={"string0,10","string1,45","string2,3", "string3,67"};
    int len = original.length;
    String result[] = new String[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len;i++) {       
        result[i] = original[i].split(",")[0];      
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

1. Declare`String result[]` array
2. Iterate the array
3. Split the record for every Iteration using `,` as delimiter
4. Now the split operation will return the array of size 2.  It contains name at index 0.
5. assign the value the `result` array.

Comment: I would add a check before the assignment to result[I] as depending on the content of original[] there may not be a ',' and you should always check for the possibility of this not being present.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `streams` and `map` from java 8 to do it:

```
String[] strings = Arrays.stream(test)
            .map(string -> string.split(",")[0])
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArraySubstring {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String test[]={"string0,10","string1,45","string2,3", "string3,67"};

        String test2[] = Arrays.stream(test).map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","))).toArray(String[]::new);
        for (String s : test2) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree this can be much simplified as @Schidu mentioned.